# Pass data to imported Python program

Tags: python, import

What I want to do is something like this:

Script1:

```
import script2
def calc():
    instance = script2.User()
    instance.user = "me"
    script2.vital_function()
```

Script2:

```
class User():
    user = ""

def vital_function():
    # Complex function that uses the User class
```

So I want to be able to run script2.py inside script1.py with variables set in script1.py. I don't think I have explained myself very clearly. Ask me if something is unclear.

Comment: So why not give `vital_function()` a parameter? `script2.vital_function(instance)`.

Comment: Wow, of course. It's early in the morning for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If user must be an object attribute, you can override the init method for the class (its constructor) and pass it the value you need it to store.

```
class User():
  def __init__(self, user):
    self.user = user

def vital_function():
    ...
```

If, instead, it must be some static value that you share among all the instances of User, either you monkey-patch it as you did, or you define a setter method

```
class User():
  user = ""

  @staticmethod
  def set_user(user):
    User.user = user
```

but I guess the first way makes more sense.
Are we missing something from your requirements?